# What is LCID 127?

Tags: asp.net, culture, lcid

In asp.net what is the culture represented by LCID 127?

```
<%Response.Write(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.LCID)%>
```

Output = 127.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the "Invariant Culture", i.e. no culture.

See [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx) of LCID's and associated cultures - it is the first one (127 = 0x007F).

Answer (score 2):

127 (`0x007F`) is the invariant culture ID.  It's a special culture - not a normal culture like English or Spanish.  You can see all the cultures in [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx).