# How to Set CultureInfo to InvariantCulture Classic ASP (VBScript)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, decimal-point, lcid, invariantculture

I am looking for a way to set a Classic ASP page's Culture Info to Invariant Culture so that the decimals have a dot and not a comma. This gives me allot of issues, On windows 8 doesn't work, get it to work on windows 8, then it doesn't work on previous versions of windows anymore.

In C# the whole thread's Culture can be set once and forget about it,

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

How can I achieve something like this with Classic ASP?
I tried setting the LCID on top of each page as well as in the session

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBScript" LCID=7177%>
```

Session:

```
Session.LCID=7177
```

But this does not work

## **EDIT:**

In `<%@ LANGUAGE="VBScript" LCID=7177%>` I Changed `LCID=7177` to `LCID="127"`

I have set `Session.LCID=127`

In IIS under `ASP` tab, I set `Locale ID` to 127

and in the Web.Config, I set globalization

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="" uiCulture="" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I am not sure, which of these made the difference, But It works now and the Decimal values have a dot in them and not a comma

Comment: This any help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297658/what-is-lcid-127 it's related to [tag:asp.net] but the `LCID` could be relevant `Session.LCID = 127`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297658/what-is-lcid-127) (I know it's [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) but should translate just fine for the `LCID`, could you not use;

```vb
'Invariant Culture
Session.LCID = 127
```